# Setting array.length for unit test

Tags: javascript, arrays, unit-testing

If I am running a unit test that is testing the logic based only on the length of a passed in array, should I be concerned about setting the length of it explicitly?

For example:

```
function foo(arrayFoo) {
  return arrayFoo.length > 10 ? 'too long' : 'just right';
}
```

And for the test:

```
let testArray = [];
testArray.length = 11;

const expected = 'too long'
const actual = foo(testArray);

expect(actual).toBe(expected);
```

I understand that this is creating an array of `undefineds` but is there a better way or am I just being paranoid?

Comment: The standard way is `new Array(11)`, which will be more canonical in your case. However, doing it the way you are doing will also work.

Comment: Using sparse arrays is considered a bad practice as general, and should be avoided even in unit tests. When you use `array.length = 5` you don't create array of 5 `undefined`s, but creates empty array with 5 holes.

Comment: @Ginden so do you have any recommended solution? Besides writing a looping function to populate a stub array.

Comment: I would use `(new Array(n)).fill('abc')` in ES6 or `(new Array(n+1)).join().split('')` in ES5.